# Migrate SwipeMenuRecyclerView to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

Have `android.enableJetifier=true`, also with the rest of the libraries working correctly.

Just this library doesn't work:
`implementation 'com.tubb.smrv:swipemenu-recyclerview:5.4.7'`

```
<com.tubb.smrv.SwipeMenuRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/transactionsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was delete `.idea` and after press `Invalidated caches/Restart`.